# Iterate over *.gz files and return where contents do NOT contain string

Tags: grep, gzip

Say I have a folder of multiple *.gz files

```
test.18.part0.json.gz  
test.19.part0.json.gz
test.20.part0.json.gz  
test.21.part0.json.gz
```

I would like to iterate over each file on the command line (Linux) and return the file names that do NOT contain a particular string

I have got as far as being able to search each file for a string

```
find . -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep "STRING"
```

But not as far as returning the filename when the contents of a file DO NOT contain said string

How could I go about this please?

Comment: `also only return the filename` what should it return?

Comment: not sure about zgrep, but if you use `grep -L 'string' <files>` then it returns filenames not containing the string.. so see if it works with zgrep too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `-v` flag to invert the match:

```
find . -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -v "STRING"
```